# jQuery smooth transition between div loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got that little piece of jQuery to load a htm file into div after you hover your mouse over a button. Here's how it looks like:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#webd').mouseenter(function () {
            $('#opis').load('portfolio/webdDescription.htm');
            }
            );
        $('#webd').mouseout(function () {
            $('#opis').load('portfolio/defaultDescription.htm');
            }
            );
    });
```

Is there any way to make those transitions smooth? Like when you hover your mouse over button, the default text fades out and meanwhile another one fades in?

Comment: you can use `.animate()` or `.fadeIn()` , `.fadeOut()`

Comment: I tried, where exactly should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some smooth transition in your load content , you can add `fadeIn()` and be something like this:

```
$('#webd').hover(function () {

  $('#opis').load('portfolio/webdDescription.htm', function(){
    $(this).css('opacity',0).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); });

},
 function(){
 $('#opis').animate({'opacity' :0}); $('#opis').load('portfolio/defaultDescription.htm',   function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); });
}
);
```

Comment: this is similar to what I've tried before, it doesn't work either. It just instantly switches to another htm and that's it.

Comment: does `#opis` has a style of `display:none`?

Comment: no, it doesn't. I don't think I want it to be display:none, because I got a little code before to load default content into #opis: jQuery('#opis').load('portfolio/defaultDescription.htm');

Comment: awesome, now it looks good :) but when you mouseover it instantly disappears, then nicely fades in. How can I add fade out?

Comment: @user2660811 , added `fadeOut()` in mouseleave event to achieve what you want :)

Comment: That's odd, when I put mouse away from the button the only difference is now, that default content is loaded with slight delay, but still the other one disappears instantly.

Comment: @user2660811, i updated my answer i remove fadeout and set the speed for fadein, are you trying to achieve the transition of disappearing?

Comment: Yeah, let me put that in points :) 1. there's a default text already loaded. 2. when you mouseover a button, the default text disappears but fading out, after that new text fades in. 3. when you put your mouse away, new text slowly disappears and default one fades in. Here's my website to visualise it. http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/

Comment: @user2660811, i've updated my answer , I use hover method instead of mouseenter and mouseleave, also I used opacity rather than fadeIn and fadeOut since that's the closest animation that you want

Comment: jQuery might be very confusing sometimes, anyway, that did the trick besides the fact that sometimes when you mouse-out it doesnt work. Thanks for you time and your help, I appreciate that! I've updated the files on the server so you can see results. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add some HTML containers for the default and web description, make those containers invisible by default, load the html files, then fadein/out on hover.

**UPDATE**

I removed all the old code/examples, this is probably going to work a lot better and is easier to expand:

```
$(function(){ 
    var el = $("#opis");
    el.load("portfolio/defaultDescription.htm").show();
    el.hover(function() {
        changeText(el, "portfolio/webdDescription.htm");
    }, function() {
        changeText(el, "portfolio/defaultDescription.htm");
    });
    function changeText(el, source) {
        el.fadeOut(function() {
            el.load(source, function() {
                el.stop().hide().fadeIn();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: woah, thanks a lot. But I don't know if it's what I need. I've got few buttons (1 for now, I will add more later), and when you hover a button it changes content of a div, that's what I got so far. Now I want the transition to be soft.

Comment: unfortunately there's a little bug.. try hover and unhover it again and again as many times see what happens

Comment: That's a silly bug indeed @DrixsonOseña, updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ceGDq/2/ but it's starting to look worse by the minute. Christian might have the better answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a "trick" to hide the content you've loaded and then apply a jQuery smooth effect to show it back.

Something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#webd').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#opis').load('portfolio/webdDescription.htm');
        $('#opis').hide();
        $('#opis').show("fade", 200);
    });
    $('#webd').mouseout(function () {
        $('#opis').load('portfolio/defaultDescription.htm');
        $('#opis').hide();
        $('#opis').show("fade", 200);
    });
});
```

Should work.

Comment: Code looks nice, but when I hover mouse over the button the defualt content disappears.

Comment: try mouseleave instead of mouseout?